# Сравнение свойст объектов и запоминание результата

Tags: javascript, jquery, инспекция-кода

Я долго думал как же сформулировать вопрос лаконично, но так и не смог. Потому сначала посмотрите код ниже. Это простой прототип, но суть он передает.

Есть некие квадратики, по которым кликает пользователь, при каждом клике сравнивается полученное значение (obj) с теми что хранятся в переменной (obj2), если есть совпадение, то происходит какое-то действие,- для примера изменяется цвет текста в div'е с соответствующим `id`. Если совпадение срабатывает в обоих случаях, то обе надписи меняют цвет и появляется слово BINGO. Когда значение переменной (obj) не соответствуют таковыми в (obj2), то цвета меняются на дефолтные и надпись BINGO пропадает.

Задачу то я решал, но выглядит это все как то "кондово", что-ли. Особенно, что касается запоминания совпадений, которое я сделал через дополнительные переменные триггеры. В общем, если кто-то сможет показать мне более элегантное и "чистое" решение или хотя бы сторону в которую копать, буду очень благодарен.

```js
var obj = {
  "red": 0,
  "blue": 0,
  "yellow": 0,
  "black": 0,
  "gray": 0
};
var obj2 = {
  "1": {
    "red": 2,
    "blue": 1,
    "yellow": 2
  },
  "2": {
    "black": 2,
    "gray": 4
  }
};
var globalTrig = {
  "1": false,
  "2": false
};
var colors = $('#colors');
showObjValues();
colors.on('click', '.color', function() {
  var key = $(this).attr('id');
  obj[key] ++;
  showObjValues();
  check();
  checkGlobalTrig();
});
colors.on('contextmenu', '.color', function() {
  var key = $(this).attr('id');
  obj[key] --;
  showObjValues();
  check();
  checkGlobalTrig();
  return false;
});

function check() {
  var trig;
  var id;
  $.each(obj2, function(key) {
    trig = true;
    id = $('#' + key);
    $.each(this, function(key, val) {
      if (obj[key] < val) {
        return trig = false;
      }
    });
    if (trig) {
      id.css('color', 'green');
    } else {
      id.css('color', '');
    }
    globalTrig[key] = trig;
  });
}

function checkGlobalTrig() {
  if (globalTrig[1] && globalTrig[2]) {
    $('#bingo').text('BINGO!!!');
  } else {
    $('#bingo').text('');
  }
}

function showObjValues() {
  var tmp = "";
  $.each(obj, function(key, val) {
    tmp += key + ": " + val + ", ";
  });
  $('#objValues').html(tmp);
}
```

```css
.color {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
#red {
  background: red;
}
#blue {
  background: blue;
}
#yellow {
  background: yellow;
}
#black {
  background: #000;
}
#gray {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bingo"></div>
<div id="objValues"></div>
<div id="1">AAAAA</div>
<div id="2">BBBBB</div>
<div id="colors">
  <div id="red" class="color"></div>
  <div id="blue" class="color"></div>
  <div id="yellow" class="color"></div>
  <div id="black" class="color"></div>
  <div id="gray" class="color"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: у вас, если докрутить до `black: 4`, а потом до `gray: 4` - оно сработает.. так и должно быть?)))

Comment: Да, сработает второе совпадение и BBB сменит цвет на зеленый, так и задумывалось.